# positioning elements using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

Let's say I have this code.

```
<div class="big_div" >
  <div class="small_div" id="small_div_1" ></div>
  <div class="small_div" id="small_div_2" ></div>
  <div class="small_div" id="small_div_3" ></div>
  <div class="small_div" id="small_div_4" ></div>
</div>

.big_div{
  width:1000px;
  height:1000px;
  background-color:green;
}
.small_div{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
#small_div_1{
  left:200px;
}
```

Ok, so I have 4 red squares on green surface, the first square (`#small_div_1`) is 200px from left side of surface, and all of them are 100px from top of surface. How I can make 3 other squares positioned next to their previous sibling (`#small_div_2` - 250px from left, `#small_div_3` - 300px from left, `#small_div_4` - 350px from left), without positioning every square separately. Because that is not problem when I have 4 squares, but when I have 100 of them, that is a problem. Is there a way of doing that using Sass or something like that, maybe JavaScript?

Comment: Use flexbox. Is AWESOME. Take a look at this: **[Guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

Comment: In any case, absolute positioning is off the table if you're looking for a scalable solution with an unknown number of elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Position elements around another with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830701/position-elements-around-another-with-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. using css: flexbox.

```css
.big_div {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
  direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.small_div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="big_div">
  <div class="small_div" id="small_div_1"></div>
  <div class="small_div" id="small_div_2"></div>
  <div class="small_div" id="small_div_3"></div>
  <div class="small_div" id="small_div_4"></div>
  <div class="small_div" id="small_div_5"></div>
  <div class="small_div" id="small_div_6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks,I had some problems with your solution,but now it's all fixed.(forgot to delete "position:absolute" for "small_div")

Answer (score 0):

I think there are more beautiful solutions but you can do this with sass too :

```
@for $i from 0 through 99 {
  #small_div_#{$i} {
    left: (200 + 50 * $i)px;
  }
}
```